# How to extrude an irregular shape into a cylinder?

Tags: mesh, faces, sculpting, extrude

As the title says, I'm trying to extrude an irregular face into a normal cylinder. There are some pics below to better describe what I want to achieve

[image: The tip of the sculpture is round]

The tip of the sculpture is round, while the bottom is pretty splash-y shaped, and as it ascends it becomes more and more round

So, is there a way to do something like that? thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<sup>Multiple Methods</sup>

#### Extrude and To Sphere

1. Extrude your edge loop upwards.
2. Type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>1</kbd> to execute the *To Sphere* command.
3. If you have overlapping vertices, try using the smooth (<kbd>W</kbd> > <kbd>O</kbd>) a couple of times and then the *To Sphere* command again.

[image: extrude and to sphere]

#### LoopTools *Circle*

1. Extrude your edge loop upwards and select it.
2. Choose the *Circle* of the LoopTools addon. It comes with Blender and has to be activated first in the *User Preferences > Addons*. It is located in the *Specials* menu. <kbd>W</kbd> *> LoopTools > Circle*.

#### Bridge to Circle

1. Select your edge loop and note the vertice-count in the info bar.
2. Add a circle, set its number of vertices equal to the edge loops.
3. Position the circle and select both, circle and previous edge loop.
4. Do the **bridge edge loops** command. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> > <kbd>L</kbd>

[image: bridge with circle]

Comment: Bridge Edgeloops is accessible via `Ctrl`+`E` menu (a bit faster to navigate).